# How can I set a relationship of the same type of the parent object?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have this Folder entity inside the CoreData model and I want to create a one-to-many relationship 'folders' of type Folder.
How can I do that?

If I do like in the screenshot, the only available 'Inverse' property is 'folders' not 'folder'.

[image]

Comment: Just create another to-one relationship and use that as the inverse one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did and it works. Thanks!

[image]